# Graph with a vertex sequence (3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to create a graph with a vertex sequence (3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2) such that there is exactly one path between every pair of vertices with distance 3 or more? And if so could it be hamiltonian graph?
I was unable to find such graph.

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: You have 9 vertices and 10 edges, so there must be 2 or 3 cycles in the graph. The distance from any other vertex to any vertices in the cycle must be at most 2, otherwise; there are two paths. Note the graph has to be connected since the path must exist. You can either enumerate the cases or find a clever argument to show it's not possible